# get value from database not working

Tags: php, database

i am trying to get a specific value from my local database but it seems that it doenst work, here's my code :

```
$acceptance = " SELECT acceptance_status FROM teams_0517 WHERE team_id=$team_id"; 
$acceptancex = mysql_query($acceptance);
mysql_close($connection);

if($acceptancex == 0)
{
    ob_clean();
    header('Location: index.php');
    ob_flush();
}
else
{
    ob_clean();
    header('Location: signup.php');
    ob_flush();
}
```

when i run the code, php will skip the if condition and continue executing other statements so it seems that  `$acceptance` don't have a value.. any help please ?

Comment: Its good practice to place an exit; after using header('Location ..');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch result after executing query.
see [how to fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

try like this:

```
$acceptance = " SELECT acceptance_status FROM teams_0517 WHERE team_id=$team_id limit 1"; 
$result = mysql_query($acceptance);
$acceptancex = mysql_fetch_object($result); // fetch object


if($acceptancex->acceptance_status == 0)
{
    ob_clean();
    mysql_close($connection);
    header('Location: index.php');
    ob_flush();
}
else
{
    ob_clean();
    mysql_close($connection);
    header('Location: signup.php');
    ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: `print_r($acceptancex);` after this line: `$acceptancex = mysql_fetch_object($result);` and die to see the result and also make sure `$team_id` is correct print this value too

Comment: it always skip the condition

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
$acceptance = " SELECT acceptance_status FROM teams_0517 WHERE team_id=$team_id limit 1"; 
$result = mysql_query($acceptance);
$acceptancex = mysql_fetch_object($result); // fetch object

if($acceptancex->acceptance_status == 0)
{
    $redirect = "index.php";
}
else
{
    $redirect = "signup.php";
}
mysql_close($connection);

ob_clean();
header('Location: '.$redirect);
ob_flush();
```